# "gcloud app deploy", deploys wrong version

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

**EDIT**: I found the issue from `.pyc` files. For some reason some compiler has created `.pyc` files which contained old code. When I uploaded files to the server, server won't compile `.py` files. Instead it will run `.pyc` files uploaded from my computer. I deleted all `.pyc` files, deployed, and now the server runs fresh code **/EDIT**

When I run `gcloud app deploy` I quite often deploy a wrong version of my app. My app is running on GAE standard environment is written using Python 2.7.

I can easily reproduce the problem by having one of my urls return a hard coded string, for example `"test1"`. Now when I change this between deployments, I quite often receive a previously written string from the endpoint.

When running the app on the local server the changed return string is correct, but after deploy the string can be from an earlier version.

I have to deploy my app to both test and production environments and I am worried about deploying wrong code. When deploying the gcloud console correctly shows that only 2 files are being uploaded (if I have only edited the static return string).

I have tried killing all other versions from the App Engine console.

Also tried using flag `--stop-previous-version`.

I have also tried adding new endpoints and after gcloud says the deployment was successful these endpoints are still inaccessible.

How can I make sure my current code gets deployed correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your note regarding the `pyc` files suggests that you may have customized your [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#runtime_and_app_elements)'s `skip_files` section and accidentally wiped its default values in the process, which would normally prevent deploying `pyc` (and other potentially interfering files) to GAE. From that doc (emphasis mine):

> The **skip_files** has the following default:
>
> ```
> skip_files:
> - ^(.*/)?#.*#$
> - ^(.*/)?.*~$
> - ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
> - ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
> - ^(.*/)?\..*$
> ```
>
> The default pattern excludes Emacs backup files with names of the form
>   `#...#` and ...~, `.pyc` and `.pyo` files, files in an `RCS` revision control directory, and Unix hidden files with names beginning with a
>   dot (.).
>
> To extend the above regular expression list, **copy and paste the above
>   list** into your `app.yaml` **and add your own** regular expressions.

So to no longer worry about manual cleaning the `.pyc` files make sure you still have the above patterns in your `skip_files` section, in particular `- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$` which is the one responsible for the `.pyc` files.

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure you change the version number in `app.yaml`

2) Go to

https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions?project={your project id}

to tell GCP which version to serve, and which to stop.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref
This page states:
`The recommended approach is to remove the version element from your app.yaml file and instead, use a command-line flag to specify your version ID`

Comment: This time point 2) wasn't the issue but it sure is good to know